# for any $k\in N$,$\lim_{m\to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\sin(\pi k2^{-i})}{\pi k2^{-i}}<\infty?$

Tags: calculus, limits

My question:  As we know that

$$\lim_{i\to \infty}\frac{\sin(\pi k2^{-i})}{\pi k2^{-i}}=1.$$

For any $k\in N$, shall we have

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\sin(\pi k2^{-i})}{\pi k2^{-i}}<\infty?$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $k \geq 1$ and $2^{-i} > 0$, it follows that $\pi k 2^{-i} > 0$

As $\sin(x) < x$ for every $x>0$, it is obvious that $\sin(\pi k 2^{-i}) < \pi k 2^{-i}.$

Thus, $\frac{\sin(\pi k 2^{-i})} {\pi k 2^{-i}} < 1.$

What you are looking for thus becomes an infinite product of fractions, all of which are lesser than $1$, (except when $i \rightarrow \infty,$ where $\frac{\sin(\pi k 2^{-i})} {\pi k 2^{-i}} \rightarrow 1$ ). Thus, the product must also be lesser than $1.$

Thus,
$\lim_{m\to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\sin(\pi k 2^{-i})} {\pi k 2^{-i}} < 1$

which implies that
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\sin(\pi k 2^{-i})} {\pi k 2^{-i}} < \infty.$$

Comment: Note that the limit exists by the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any proof of the following statements but there were carefully checked : considering k > 0, it seems that if k is even the limit of the product is effectively zero. But, if k is odd, the product has a finite value (not very large but finite).

Comment: I also think so. But we need proof, or it's not persuasive.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I just wanted to show the result which could give some evidences for the proof. Sorry for not being better in this (and so many other) area !

Comment: Thank you all the same! :)